# Angular 5 : Displaying an Updated Data not automatically

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean

My data not displayed automatically after the button pressed. I need refresh the page to show the updated data, how to make it automatically updated after the button pressed?

[image]

Typescript file of updateProfileCompany :

```
updateProfileCompany(){
var getUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
getUser = JSON.parse(getUser)
var id_student = getUser["id"];
var nim        = getUser["nim"];
var nama       = getUser["nama"];
var email      = getUser["email"];
var company    = this.company

let user = {
  id         : id_student,
  nama       : nama,
  email      : email,
  nim        : nim,
  company    : this.company
}
console.log(user.company);
this.authService.updateProfileCompany(user)
.subscribe(user => user);}
```

My Service :

```
updateProfileCompany(user){
let headers = new Headers();
this.loadToken();
var users = localStorage.getItem(this.user);
headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
return this.http.put('http://192.168.100.3:3000/users/update', user, {headers: headers})
.map(res => res.json());}
```

Express Endpoints for updating the data :

```
router.put('/update', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next)=>{
    const user = req.body;
    var id_student = user.id;
    var id_company = user.company
    var result = [];
    User.findById(id_student, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send({message: "Error"});
        }
        if(!user) {
            return res.status(404).send({message: "User Not Found"});            
        }
        user.company = id_company;
        result.push(user);
        user.save(function(err, user){
            if(err) {
                return res.status(500).send({message: "Cannot Update, please try again"});
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                return res.status(200).send({message: "Update Success"});
                console.log('Your data has been updated.');
            }
        }); 
        if(id_company){
            Company.findById(id_company, function(err, company) {
                company.students.addToSet(id_student)
                company.save(function(err, company){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log('Your data has been updated.');
                    result.push(company);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to assign user to class level user variable in subscribe. `.subscribe(user => {this.user = user});`

Comment: @fatih ranjeet8082 said you need to update the value of the 'user' property  of the class because at the end 'user' property is used to show data. You need to do it manually by assigning the value to this.user

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch Data from the server after successfully Updation of information of user like this:-

```
return this.http.put('http://192.168.100.3:3000/users/update', user, {headers: headers})
.map(res => {
    /* Write call to get updated information from the server and Update your view accordinly */
    return res.json();
  }
})
```

Comment: what's the error now? can you please update your question with call you added to fetch updated data?

Comment: There's no error from your code, but what I want is display the updated data after add company button was pressed

Comment: Yes, I am getting your point. for that you need to get updated data from server and bind manually after successfully updation which I am trying to explain in my answer